# Sorting With Inconsistent Comparisons

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

I'm trying to chart performance metrics taken over a wide period of time, but my data is noisy and the sensor drifts substantially over time, so adjacent measurements are reasonably good but the absolute measurements over time aren't meaningful.  I can randomize the order of the measurements, but I don't know how to interpret the results.

It occurred to me that the problem is similar to the game where users are shown two random girls, they choose the girl on the left or the girl on the right, and the system figures out who the hottest girls are.  You can get situations where the humans are inconsistent, but globally arrive at a rough consensus.

Unlike the game problem, I get approximate distances as the result of a comparison.  If A takes 2ms longer than B, that's very different from A taking 200ms longer than B (in the first case they're roughly equivalent and strict order doesn't matter, in the second case they are very different and probably live far apart in an ordered list).  I feel like this information should (in some way) be useful for minimizing the number of comparisons I need to do.  I can choose the order in which I perform measurements.

I imagine that this is a well-studied problem in computer science or mathematics (sorting algorithms where the comparator is noisy/inconsistent).  What is the name of the best algorithm for this use case?

Thanks!

Comment: That's an interesting problem to solve, but it seems a bit broad. Can you specify the "Question" of your post in a way that makes it obvious what kind of an answer you would consider to be a solution to your problem?

Comment: I cleaned up the last sentence to be more of a direct ask.  Basically, I'm looking for pointers/directions/keywords that I can use to research the topic.  I'm happy to do my own research, but I don't even know where to start.  There must be an out-of-the-box algorithm for this; I can't believe it's not a well studied/understood problem in some circles.

Comment: For sensor drift, the first thing that comes to mind is to simply normalize the data over a rolling average.  As long as the "real average" doesn't drift, it's probably fine.

Comment: This is a problem in statistics, and perhaps in experimental design. My guess is that the experimental designers will tell you to calibrate your sensor every now and then, and the mathematical statisticians will tell you how to fit a model to make the best use of your (now more easily interpreted) data.